# StreamReader to multiple listboxes

Tags: c#, listbox, streamreader

I am attempting to use the StreamReader to break data from a text file into multiple listboxes. Thus far, I 've been able to get all the data into *one* listbox, but the next step of my project requires the data to be split and I think I understand listboxes better than arrays. I have made an effort to search for a similar problem, but because I am a beginner, most of what I have found perplexes me further. I have only been able to accomplish the following successfully:

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
string data;
while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
    data = file.ReadLine();
    listBox1.Items.Add(data);
}
file.Close();
```

My data in my .txt file comes in blocks of three like so:

```
blue
david
8042
red
joseph
7042
```

I am unable to change the data format, so I have been trying to code it out in such a way that

```
if (blue)
    listBox1.Items.Add(david);
    listBox2.Items.Add(8042);
else if (red)
    listBox3.Items.Add(joseph);
    listBox4.Items.Add(7042);
```

etc. I only have two colors to work with, but lots of data for each of those colors. My problem is that I am new to coding and failing to put into place the basics I've learned to do such a thing.

What are the lines of code I'm missing to add a line *below* a line to a listbox while it StreamReads? Do I need to use an

```
int counter = 0;
```

and increase it by 1 or 2 to get those lines, or am I thinking too basically?

Thank you very much for any help. I feel like I'm missing something very simple I have yet to grasp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way out is reading by *three lines* (i.e. *entire block*) instead of *one*:

```
  using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {
    while (!file.EndOfStream) {
      string color = file.ReadLine();
      string name = file.ReadLine();
      string number = file.ReadLine();

      if (color == "blue") {
        listBox1.Items.Add(name);
        listBox2.Items.Add(number);
      }
      else if (color == "red") {
        listBox3.Items.Add(name);
        listBox4.Items.Add(number);
      }
    }  
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry! You showed me exactly what I was missing.